# Is it possible to find a zip password if it is being generated locally?

Tags: passwords, exploit, zip

I have a program that generates a zip file with a password. Is it possible to determine the password if you analyse the program as it is being run? Would calls to function libraries show the password or is there no way to determine the password?

Comment: If someone has access to the machine being used by a zip tool, they can just install a keylogger (and a clipboard monitor, and a screen recorder).  It is easier to use "standard" malware than to implement a new malware for zip.  Or they can just replace the zip tool with one that's been compromised.  Admittedly, such approaches typically require admin access, whereas monitoring a user-mode zip utility does not.

Answer (score 3):

If a password is used, it must exist somewhere readable at some point in time. Whether or not the password is stored in obfuscated or encrypted form will determine what approach is needed in order to recover it. If it is simply stored as a string, hardcoded in the source, static analysis or even running `strings` on the program may reveal the password. Otherwise, you may need to do dynamic analysis (debugging or hooking functions; dumping memory perhaps) at the point of which the password is used.

Comment: On some operating systems, it's also possible to access the content of a (password) textbox via standard APIs, on condition that the access is done by an application with equal or greater access permission than the zip utility..

Answer (score 0):

If it is a static password, then static binary analysis (with a decompiler/debugger) is your friend.
If it is a password generated on run (dynamic password generation) then static binary analysis is your friend.

Comment: Did you mean to say "dynamic binary analysis" in one of your examples?